# Adding role to node does not work

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe, knife

I am following exact syntax but seeing some strange behavior while adding role to one of my nodes

I am running following command which should ideally add role - webserver to do_node

```
knife node run_list add do_node 'role[webserver]'
```

But instead this is what is returned:

```
do_node:
 run_list: recipe[roles]
```

Also the show node command shows something gone wrong:

```
Run List:    recipe[roles]
Roles:
```

My workstation is a Win7 machine & using the hosted chef. Tried multiple times but same thing. Tried verbose output which does not reveal a whole lot!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

What is likely happening is that

```
role[webserver]
```

is being interpreted as a glob and is completing to the 'roles' directory in your chef directory.  Thus, from knife's perspective, you've entered:

```
knife node run_list add do_node roles
```

which it upconverts to 'recipe[roles]'.  Typically single quotes avoids this type of globbing, but I've seen issue crop up with mingw.  You can confirm that this is the problem by trying to add a role that won't match a folder in your current directory:

```
knife node run_list add do_node 'role[foo]'
```

The best way to quote your original command depends a bit on your shell and terminal setup, but you may try the following:

```
knife node run_list add do_node '"role[webserver]"'
```

or (with double-quotes on the *outside* of the run list item)

```
knife node run_list add do_node "'role[webserver]'"
```

There are a number of bugs filed against this in the Chef issue tracker.  Here is one: https://tickets.opscode.com/browse/CHEF-4277

Comment: Thanks a lot, that's quite close - you spotted the problem right. Though the '"role[webserver]"' is not working on my machine - doing the same thing as earlier! Need

Comment: I think "'role[webserver]'" did the trick instead of '"role[webserver]"'

Comment: Like (I think) @vishal.biyani commented, `"'role[webserver]'"` (i.e. with the double-quotes on the *outside*) worked in a MINGW32 ("Git Bash") terminal window, but not with the double-quotes on the inside.